# Refactor rename custom annotation class member fields in java using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I created custom annotation for class member fields in java, for eg.

In file A.java

```
Public Class A {
   @Set
   private String tempString = "hello";
}
```

In file B.java

```
public Class B {
   @Use
   private String tempString;
}
```

In file A.java member field tempString is set to "hello" and in file B.java I am consuming it. Both of these annotation works fine. Now I would like to know is there a way to refactor rename variable "tempString" in eclipse by which I make change to A.java tempString -> temp then it automatically rename tempString -> temp in B.java? If not then how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

The two variables **tempString** are not "related" in Java terms.

The compiler can't see that one use the other and can't discover by itself the logical relation between your 2 annotations.

So Eclipse refactoring can't do that as is.

If you want to achieve this kind of refactoring you have to develop an Eclipse plugin of your own, specific to your project.

Comment: I was also thinking about writing eclipse plugin but just wanted to make sure that is there any other way I can achieve this. Thanks for clarifying it.